# Tic Tac Toe Minimax algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the **minimax** algorithm for finding the best move for a computer in response to a human move. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Unh51VnD-hA) video from UCB. I need some help regarding the algorithm.

```
//Data Structures used :

#define NO_OF_MAX_MOVES 9
char board[9] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
int bestPosition;

int getNextBestMove(int player)
{
int i, currentMoveScore;

// humanPlayer = 0;
// computerPlayer = 1;

if (isGameWon() == 1)
{
    return 1;   // computer has won
}
else if (isGameWon() == -1)
{
    return -1;  // human has won
}
else if (isGameDrawn())
{
    return 0;
}

int bestScore;
if(player == 0)
{
    bestScore = 2;  // for human
}
else
{
    bestScore = -2;  // for computer
}

for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    if(board[i] == ' ')
    {
        if(player == 1)   //  computer is playing so maximize
        {
            board[i] = 'O';
            currentMoveScore = getNextBestMove(0);  // res stores the various tree leaf values

            board[i] = ' ';
            if(currentMoveScore > bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = currentMoveScore;
                bestPosition = i;
            }
        }

        else if (player == 0)  // player is playing so minimise
        {
            board[i] = 'X';
            currentMoveScore = getNextBestMove(1);
            board[i] = ' ';
            if (currentMoveScore > bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = currentMoveScore;
                bestPosition = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

return bestScore;
}
```

Once, I call this method **getNextBestMove(1);**, the variable ** bestPosition** should give me the index of the next best move.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `if (isGameWon() == 1) else if (isGameWon)` ?

Comment: oh sorry typo ! Correcting !!

Comment: Properly indenting your code increases your chances to get an answer by 650%. Confirmed by the Royal Academy. Also, your comment says one player is maximizing and the other is minimizing, but the code says they both do the exact same thing.

Comment: `getNextBestMove` returns `bestScore`...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is :-

For min player you should have  `if (currentMoveScore < bestScore)`  but the code is evaluating max instead of min.